# Python: How do I sum a line full of integers one by one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, sum, line

I have several lines full of integers(from a .txt file), and I want to sum every signle integer one by one for each line.

Example:

```
37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250 line0 = sum_of_numbers
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538 line1 = sum_of_numbers
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629 .
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250 .
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676 .
89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757 .
28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738 .
44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318 .
47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276 .
70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951 line9 = sum_of_numbers
```

Comment: Share what you've tried so far and we can help you in the right direction.

Comment: This looks like an assignment question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this to iterate through the lines of your file and sum the numbers.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(sum(int(char) for char in line.strip()))
```

If there is a chance your lines may not be all digits the you will need to use this instead to check.

```
print(sum(int(char) for char in line if char.isdigit()))
# no need for .strip() since \n characters are not a digit
```

Comment: @steven-summers: you can omit `.strip()` when using `.isdigit()` check

Comment: True, I'll add that in then

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open('foo.txt', 'r')

def sum_line(line):
  return sum(int(c) for c in line.strip())

line_sums = [sum_line(line) for line in f]
```